# File Object Not Defined NuxtJS AsyncData()

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS's AsyncData method to fetch a video file from an API and then return to the page as a file object.

Like so:

```
async AsyncData({$axios}){
    var user_video = null;
    try{
        var video = $axios.get("my awesome url");
        user_video = new File([video], "video.mp4",{type:"video/mp4"}); // <= this line
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("no saved video");
    }

    return {user_video};
}
```

In in the server side console, it shows this error:

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
    at asyncData (pages/send/video.js:155:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
no saved video
```

I've looked at other nuxtjs `Content` keys to use that may have something to do with creating a new File Object, but i have not found any. https://nuxtjs.org/api/context

I've tried searching for a similar error with using the `File` object in asyncdata, though I have not found anything.

Any suggestions?

Edit ----  Also To Add:

**the URL I am fetching from brings to a download dialogue box in case this may be related.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asyncData is executed on server on first load. And on server there no such thing as File in node. So you cant use File on your server code.

You should either dont use File or dont use asyncData and use mounted hook to fetch and set your data.

Comment: Thanks this opened my eyes. i had a work around to set the source of the video straight to the URL instead of fetching the URL first as I'm trying to do in my original post.